# Laravel Blade Iterate with Different Loops

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to do iterate with two different loops in my Blade file but the results keep repeating the numbers.

**Results**

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

**These are the results I want.**

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

**Blade**

```php
@foreach($driver_recs as $page => $driver)
    <div class="form-container">
        @foreach($trip_count as $val => $trip)
            @if($val == 2)
                {{ $loop->parent->iteration }}
            @endif
        @endforeach
        {{ $loop->iteration + 1 }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: what does `$driver_recs` look like?

Comment: A huge array, I thought about using $page but same problem. https://www.pastiebin.com/5c542ec147081

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to output from this huge arrray

Comment: I am just trying to do a basic counter with using different loops without repeating the same number twice like how I have in my results.

Comment: Bit hard to help when we can't see `$driver_recs`, `$trip_count`, or the actual output of your blade code (it outputs HTML, not columns of numbers).  Pls try [creating an MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - eg define some dummy arrays with sets of numbers - and showing it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your numbers into chunks of 2 and then render them easily.

```
@foreach (collect(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)->chunk(2) as $chunk) {
    <div class="form-container">
        @foreach ($chunk as $number) {
            {{ $number }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Tying up your code logic to specific iteration numbers is *a bad practice* and a very big indication that you are probably doing things wrong.